# drawRect not called in subclass of AsyncImageView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, drawrect, rounded-corners

In my project I need to use `AsyncImageView` to load images. I also want those images to be circular. The images appear in table views mostly, so I couldn't use roudned corners on the `AsyncImageView's` layer, because that had very, very negative effects on the performance of the app.

So what I decided to do is to create a subclass of `AsyncImageView` (because I needed the original non-circular AsyncImageView for other views in my project), called `RoundedAsyncImageView`, in which I only implemented the `drawRect` method like this:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGPathRef clippath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect cornerRadius:17].CGPath;
    CGContextAddPath(ctx, clippath);
    CGContextClip(ctx);
    [self.image drawInRect:rect];
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
}
```

I have xib's for the cells in which this circular image should appear, created with IB. So I just changed the custom class of the `UIImageView` element to `RoundedAsyncImageView` and the `IBOutlet`s of the image view to `RoundedAsyncImageView`. The problem now is that `drawRect` is not getting called. Any ideas why?

EDIT:
I read that `UIImageView` subclasses don't call drawRect, and that I should simply draw the image in a regular `UIView` subclass. Problem is, I can't actually do that, as I need the `AsyncImageView`'s functionality for asynchronously loading images. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DrawRect` method on `UIImageView` is slightly different than `UIView`

> The view still has a CALayer, but the layer doesn’t allocate a backing store. Instead it uses a CGImageRef as its contents and the render server will draw that image’s bits into the frame buffer.
>
> In this case, there’s no drawing going on. We’re simply passing bitmap data in form of an image to the UIImageView.

refer to this article [Getting Pixels onto the Screen](http://www.objc.io/issue-3/moving-pixels-onto-the-screen.html),And as my experience,that's why you can't get your imageView clip method worked.

Here is my solution:

1. Instead of creating a subclass of `AsyncImageView`, create a subClass of `UIView`.
2. Add `AsyncImageView` , which means your subClass become a wrapper view of `AsyncImageView`.
3. Implement the clip method in drawRect, and let asyncImageView handle it's content changes.

Comment: Like I said, I don't want to use cornerRadius as it has adverse effects on the performance of the table views (i.e scrolling). So if I use your solution with drawRect, how exactly could I do this? It would mean that in the UIView subclass I would need to have a drawRect method that changes the AsyncImageView somehow, right?

Comment: the drawRect method won't change the asyncImageView, the only purpose of this view it's for clipping your imageView. implement the clip method in drawRect, and let asyncImageView handle it's content changes.

Comment: So this UIView is going to be a wrapper arround AsyncImageView, right?

Comment: Please expand you original answer so that we can mark it as correct.

Comment: I did all of this, and the images are not rounded, they appear square.